# Why Fedora cannot boot on 8GB of RAM from liveUSB (with rd.live.ram option)?

Tags: fedora, live-usb

Recently when I tried to boot Fedora on another laptop (it booted fine before) it halted.
[image]

Took me some time and several tries to realize it lacks enough ram. It booted on same laptop with 16GB of ram, but failed when I left only one 8GB module. Below are some outputs of `df` and `free`, as far as I see on them 8GB should be enough as for 16GB 12GB is available when booted. Linux Mint which I use much more than Fedora boots fine on 8GB for ram, size of ISO file is about same.

Fedora on 16GB:

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                3.1G  2.0G  1.2G  63% /run
/dev/mapper/live-rw  7.8G  5.5G  2.3G  71% /
tmpfs                7.7G   36K  7.7G   1% /tmp
vartmp               7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs                1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1             15G  5.4G  8.6G  39% /run/media/liveuser/usb
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ free -hw
               total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       832Mi        11Gi       2.2Gi        35Mi       3.2Gi        12Gi
```

LM on 16GB:

```
mint@mint:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/shm        2.2G  2.1G  103M  96% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            7.7G   28M  7.7G   1% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G   32K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
```

LM on 8GB:

```
mint@mint:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           767M  1.6M  765M   1% /run
/dev/shm        2.2G  2.1G  103M  96% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            3.8G   28M  3.8G   1% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           767M   40K  767M   1% /run/user/999

mint@mint:~$ free -hw
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:          7.5Gi       754Mi       3.8Gi       2.3Gi       162Mi       2.8Gi       4.2Gi
    Swap:          8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi
```

Comment: Bad memory? Can you check it?

Comment: @K-att- why such a hypothesis?

Comment: Some bad bits can cause problems.

Comment: @K-att- IMO with that logic all software errors can be blamed on bad memory. What makes you think the issue I've described has more chances to be due to bad memory than others?

Comment: @Artem, why do you write "the same"? It boots with rd.live.ram, only when amount of ram is large enough and I want to know why it needs at boot time amount of ram about at least twice as large than when boot completed.